# Deriving insights from results of k-means algorithm

Tags: regression, clustering, k-means

Here is youth unemployment kaggle dataset ( https://www.kaggle.com/sovannt/world-bank-youth-unemployment )that I've executed k-means on where k=3 :

Sample data, showing 3 rows :

```
         2011       2012       2013       2014  
0   20.900000  19.700001  21.100000  20.799999  
1   10.700000  10.700000  10.600000  10.500000  
2   27.000000  28.299999  28.700001  29.200001
```

[image]

What can infer from this visualization ?

Here are my thoughts :

```
1. Youth unemployment follows a linear regression line.
2. As youth unemployment increases the unemployment variance figure also increases - suggests these are correlated.
```

Update :

k-means has been executed against all four (2011 - 2014 inclusive) years and all data points (not just sample data above). The distance between each point is euclidean.

Comment: K-means isn't designed for use with time series data. Given that, it might be worth wondering whether these results are "too good to be true" and an artifact of something in the data, e.g., a trend function requiring detrending to uncover more realistic relationships. A good reference for clustering time series are the chapters in Aggarwal and Reddy's book, *Data Clustering: Algorithms and Applications*.

Comment: To me, the plot is useless. You already know from linear regression they are linearly correlated. Then you use k-means to compute 3 clusters. Of course, the distance function clusters all the closest points like in your plot.

Comment: You should also tell us the x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: Your interpretation does not use k-means.

Comment: I can't tell what you did. What are the axes of your plot? Are they 2 of the years? Which? Did you use all 4 years displayed in the example matrix for the k-means?

Comment: @gung please see update

Comment: What are the axes? Are they 2 of the 4 years? Which?

Comment: @gung I used Python scikit-learn package to generate this visualization. I assume it's performing PCA on the dataset but I'll need to research the scikit-learn k-means implementation in order to fully understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data itself is highly correlated.

The "regression" you are seeing is that unemployment rates do not tend to change drastically from year x to year x+1 (surprise... it takes more than a year to change the job market situation).

If you apply PCA and visualize the first two components, it looks like this:

[image]

Which clearly shows that there is **only one cluster** (and some outliers). The first two components roughly correspond to X) the average unemployment rate, and Y) the change since 2010. Points at the top right (e.g. Greece) have high unemployment, and rising. Points in the bottom have above average (x larger than 0) unemployment, but decreasing.

I doubt doing clustering on this data set is meaningful. If the visualization does not show clusters, **there probably are no clusters**.